# How to change the theme of a program

Tags: themes

I have a piece of software, a winform program developed in c#, that has several different themes. But if one of my team members wants to change the theme they have to ask me, then i have to change it, recompile and send it. Instead I wish for them to be able to freely change the theme. It is like changing the theme in Firefox, etc. Any ideas on how to begin coding such a piece of software?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good thing to put into your config file.  Have a method that checks the config file for a theme setting.  And change the theme based on that.  I would also recommend having a default theme in case the config file fails to specify one.

Alternatively, this could go into the admin / settings / options portion of the application.  Where you could save it with your other settings.  In the registry, or app settings folder, etc.